# How do I make the numbers count down each time the user inputs something?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
while flag:
    x = input("Input name or press \'q\' to quit:\n")
    x = x.lower()
    for char in x:
        if char.isdigit():
            print("Your name cannot be a number. Please type your name again:\n")
            continue
    if x == "q":
        flag = False
    elif x == "abe":
        print("Welcome back, Abe")
        flag = False
    else:
        i = 4
        i-= 1
        while i > 0:
            print(f"Incorrect name. Please try again. You have {i} tries remaining.\n")
            i-= 1
            break
            if i == 0:
                print("You have run out of tries. System is locked.")
                break
```

This is something I was playing around with after I first started learning python a couple days ago. I understand why the number isn't changing but I can't think of a way to make the number different each time it asks for input.
Also, if the user inputs a sequence of numbers and letters, the error messages repeat for each number in the input. How would I write it so that as soon as a number is detected, one error message is sent and the loop is restarted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things to improve in this code, I will list all the ones I could find and provide the corrected code.

- Consider using a `while True` loop.
- You needn't check each character in the input for `isdigit()`. Is digit does that already. For example, `"foo_bar".isdigit()` return False, `"123".isdigit()` returns True and `"foo_123_bar".isdigit()` returns False.
- Use the `break` keyword to exit while loops ([read more on break](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm)).
- Define `i = 4` before the loop starts, otherwise it gets re-initialized to 4 every time a wrong input is encountered and thus never changes.
- You don't need a loop inside a loop to keep track of remaining tries (see code below).

```
# Number of tries
i = 4

while True:
  # Read and process input 
  x = input("Input name or press \'q\' to quit:\n")
  x = x.lower()

  # Check if input is digit
  if x.isdigit():
      print("Your name cannot be a number. Please type your name again:\n")
      continue

  # Check if input is 'quit'
  if x == 'q':
      break

  # Check if input is 'abe'
  elif x == 'abe':
      print('Welcome back, Abe')
      break

  # Wrong input, take appropriate action
  else:
    # User has tries remaining, warn user
    if i > 0:
      print(f'Incorrect name. Please try again. You have {i} tries remaining.\n')
      i -= 1

    # User has runout of tries, lock system
    else:
      print("You have run out of tries. System is locked.")
      break
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is you are defining `i` inside the loop. Instead you should define it outside.

Here is the code;

```
i = 4
flag = True
while flag:
    x = input("Input name or press \'q\' to quit:\n")
    x = x.lower()
    for char in x:
        if char.isdigit():
            print("Your name cannot be a number. Please type your name again:\n")
            continue
    if x == "q":
        flag = False
    elif x == "abe":
        print("Welcome back, Abe")
        flag = False
    else:
        i-= 1
        while i > 0:
            print(f"Incorrect name. Please try again. You have {i} tries remaining.\n")
            break
            if i == 0:
                print("You have run out of tries. System is locked.")
                break
```

Please comment if you need more explanation

Comment: Thank you so much!
How could I solve the problem of the error message repeating if there are multiple numbers in the input?

Comment: please mark it as accepted and leave an upvote. Thanks

Comment: My code provides an answer to the question mentioned here.

Comment: I there are many more things to improve in this code as the inner loop is completely unnecessary. Check below for my code,, perhaps it will be useful to you.

Comment: My code simply solves the problem mentioned. As he is a beginner, he will learn it on his own how to modify code. I just followed the question

Comment: @Irfanwani I agree. I just thought if any one in the future visits this thread, it would be useful to have all the mistakes pointed out so that they may not repeat it :)

Answer (score 0):

> How would I write it so that as soon as a number is detected, one error message is sent and the loop is restarted?

In the top part, you are iterating through *every character* of the string. So naturally, if the character is a digit, it will print the error message. Hence your problem.

You can change it to:

```
x = x.lower()
if not x.isalpha():
    print("Your name cannot be a number. Please type your name again:\n")
    continue
```

The `str.isalpha()` method checks if all characters of the string are alphabets.

> I understand why the number isn't changing but I can't think of a way to make the number different each time it asks for input.

Please clarify this part!

Comment: I wanted the variable i to count down each time the wrong name was inputted. However someone else already solved that issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackOverflow. I think you probably wanted to implement something like this:

```
i  =  4
while i>0:
    x = input("Input name or press \'q\' to quit:\n")
    x = x.lower()
    for char in x:
        if char.isdigit():
            print("Your name cannot be a number. Please type your name again.\n")
            break
    if x == "q":
        i = 0
    elif x == "abe":
        print("Welcome back, Abe")
        i = 0
    else:
        i -= 1
        if i:
            print(f"Incorrect name. Please try again. You have {i} tries remaining.\n")
        else:
            print("You have run out of tries. System is locked.")
            break
```

Let me know if you would like to add more functionality.